tf.test.is_built_with_cuda() return false
I use Ubuntu/Linux to create a virtual environment with Anaconda and use VSCode for machine learning development.
The problem is that after I installed CUDA and cuDNN, I used tf.test.is_built_with_cuda() to test if the GPU can be used, but it returned FALSE.
Here are the steps I followed to install CUDA and cuDNN:
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/cudatoolkit-10.0.130-0.conda
conda install cudatoolkit-10.0.130-0.conda 
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/cudnn-7.6.5-cuda10.0_0.conda
conda install cudnn-7.6.5-cuda10.0_0.conda

Version
Python 3.6.13 :: Anaconda, Inc.
tensorflow        1.14.0     pypi_0        pypi
tensorflow-gpu    1.14.0     pypi_0        pypi
cudatoolkit       10.0.130        0        <unknown>
cudnn              7.6.5     cuda10.0_0    <unknown>


I have solved my problem !
In the Anaconda environment, when installing TensorFlow-GPU, you should use the conda instead of pip. For example, conda install tensorflow-gpu.
